# Are SMC samples uncorrelated?

Tags: correlation, monte-carlo, resampling

In [this](http://www.pnas.org/content/104/6/1760.full.pdf) paper the authors list advantages of SMC. One of them is:

> Unlike MCMC, SMC particles are uncorrelated and do not require the
>   determination of a burn-in period or assessment of convergence.

However, I believe that they are not uncorrelated after the resampling. Could someone help me understand why they would be uncorrelated?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a misunderstanding in your question. In SMC, you start with a sample $X^{1:n}$ and you transform it into a sample $\tilde{X}^{1:n}$ which is approximately from the target distribution. So, there is no burn-in, nor correlation, nor chain involved.

See:

http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~guillou/meeting/cappe.pdf

http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/johansen/talks/20090309.pdf

Comment: I believe the question related to things like the [bootstrap particle filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_filter#Sequential_importance_Resampling_.28SIR.29). In that case, for 100 particles, 50 might share the same history for $t\leq T$, even though there states at $t=T+1$ differ. So "correlated" may refer to cloned essentially?

Comment: @GeoMatt22: yes, we might call them cloned. Cloned seem to be correlated for me but maybe I'm wrong.